# How can I pass an extra parameter to a link_to remote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following:

```
<%= link_to "Add", group_request_path(gr), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method=> :put, :remote => true %>

<%= link_to "Ignore", group_request_path(gr), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method=> :put, :remote => true %>
```

How can I pass a decision param with either add or ignore in the `link_to`'s above? Is there an option to add a URL param somehow with a link_to? I don't want to have to use forms.

Comment: gr here equals a GroupRequest object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `*_path` helpers accept a hash of options to append to the path as a query string.

In your example, assuming `group_request_path(gr)` outputs something like `/group_requests/123`, you could add a query string with add/ignore actions like this:

```
group_request_path(gr, :action => 'add') # /groups_requests/123?action=add
```

or

```
group_request_path(gr, :add => 1) # /groups_requests/123?add=1
```

However this probably isn't the correct way of going about this. It looks like you should probably have distinct actions in your controller, and routes specific to adding or ignoring.  You'll have to add something like the following to `config/routes.rb`:

```
put 'group_requests/:id/add'    => 'groups_requests#add',    :as => :add_group_request
put 'group_requests/:id/ignore' => 'groups_requests#ignore', :as => :ignore_group_request
```

Your links then become

```
<%= link_to "Add", add_group_request_path(gr), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method=> :put, :remote => true %>

<%= link_to "Ignore", ignore_group_request_path(gr), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method=> :put, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: Your first solution fit the bill nicely. Thank you!

Comment: @ColdTree I have to reiterate, the first solution is definitely not the "rails way". You should define two actions named `add` and `ignore` in your controller and route to them via `/groups/.../add` and `/groups/.../ignore`